# SSH smoke & mirrors

Tags: unix, ssh, putty

**Situation:**
I've been given SSH access to a server running LAMP (Redhat) and the brief is to migrate files and database from current live server to this new development server for testing.
Further this SSH access is contained within a Protected Workspace, so basically I have to access this companies internal network and then I can access the server there through SSH.

**Issue:**
SSH - WTF?? :- In the murky world of media agency smoke and mirrors alas I'm not allowed to  admit weakness and it appears that I won't have access to my familiar tools (filezilla + sequelpro)

I managed to logon to the server yesterday with Putty though have no idea how to achieve the mission:

- Create a database
- Import data to that database
- Upload files
- Set permission on files and folders
- At what address will I be able to view the website?

Is there a kind soul out there who can point me in the right direction?

Thanks.

Comment: Well only takes 2 seconds to give him the basic tools: WinSCP for file stuff, phpMyAdmin for the database stuff.  The address for the site is the same that you are using for ssh.

Comment: Thanks John. So WINSCP provides a friendlier UI for SSH/SFTP. I can then upload a copy of phpMyadmin and connect that way if needs be. re: address - ok thanks for clarifying that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the problem with FileZilla? If its available on the server - run it, SSH has nothing to do with that. You'll probably want to have X server running on your computer though, and set up port forwarding in Putty to allow applications running through SSH to connect to it.

SSH is what it is: secured shell connection. Once you gained access through SSH you can do everything you could do using local console.

Comment: I have FileZilla installed on my machine, it's not available on the remote server however if that's what you're referring to. re X Server - do you mean this: http://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/ ? Would I need X Server in order to be to work with something like WINSCP?